# Using VIM, how do I remap directional keys from right hand to left hand?

Tags: vim, remapping, right-to-left

This is the best solution I've seen so far:

```
" Map Right Directionals to Left Commands
noremap s h
noremap d k
noremap f j
noremap g l

" Map Left Commands to Right Directionals
noremap h s
noremap k d
noremap j f
noremap l g
```

However, when actually using this mapping, it requires a double-press on the 's' and 'g' keys when switching from left to right.

Is there a better way to re-map these keys to work 100% correctly without the need to double-press keys?

Comment: Spontaneously I don't really see the application. It's just a question of habit - if you are used to using your right hand for movement keys, this will be the most convenient, left-handed or not. In games the standard is to use the left hand for movement (WASD), and I as right-handed have no trouble with this. Normally I think getting used to custom keyboard shortcuts is mostly unnecessary, and annoying when one has to use someone else's settings for any reason. Allright, I'll stop rambling aimlessly now :-) .

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The mappings work for me in a plain Vim (`vim -N -u NONE`); you probably have some other mappings that start with `s` or `g`, and therefore Vim has to wait for a next keypress to resolve the ambiguity. Check for such mappings with

```
:verbose nmap s
:verbose nmap g
```

and remove / redefine those mappings.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to `nnoremap` it prevents recursive mappings.

Comment: I tried `nnoremap` but it doesn't change the results...still need to double-press left and right keys when switching directions.